# How to convert an array into JSON format

Tags: javascript

For Example:

```
var arr = ["tag1, tag2"]
```

I want to have the above array in `JSON` format as follows:

```
var arr = [
    {"name": "tag1"},
    {"name": "tag2"}
]
```

Can someone please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: That is not "JSON format". Recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var arr = ["tag1", "tag2"];
var json= [];
arr.forEach(e => json.push({name:e}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You input array should be like, Then you can use array.map to iterate over objects and create new objects

```
var arr = ["tag1", "tag2"]
```

**DEMO**

```js
var arr = ["tag1", "tag2"];

var  newList = arr.map(v => {
  return Object.assign({}, { Name: v })
});
console.log(newList);
```

Comment: `Unexpected token =>` its giving error in angularjs

Comment: you must be missing a syntax

Comment: I have written correct syntax but it's giving same error

Comment: produce a demo using fiddle

Comment: my actual problem is I have two arrays and in that two array remove the duplicate values from that array. but both the array format is different one is `var l1 = [{'id': 2,'name':'tag1'}, {'id': 3, 'name':'tag2'}, {'id': 4, 'name':'tag3'}]` and another one is var l2 = ["tag5", "tag2", "tag3", "tag6"]; these are two different type of array is there

Comment: so I want to remove duplicate from values from this two array.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do this on your array using `map` function:

```js
var objArray = ["tag1", "tag2"].map(el => {
  return { name: el };
});
console.log(objArray);
```

if your problem is having 2 different arrays as you mentioned in a comment above & you want to remove duplicate tags, you could do this:

```js
var l1 = [
  {'id': 2,'name':'tag1'}, 
  {'id': 3, 'name':'tag2'}, 
  {'id': 4, 'name':'tag3'}];

var l2 = [ "tag5", "tag2", "tag3", "tag6" ];

l2 = l2.map(el => {
  return { name: el };
});

// concat both the arrays
var src = l1.concat(l2);

// remove duplicates
var temp = [];
const unique = src.filter(item => {
  if (temp.indexOf(item.name) === -1) {
    temp.push(item.name);
    return item;
  }
});
console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var obj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"};

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

thats it...!